# spark python product top 5 numbers from a file

Tags: python, apache-spark

total noob question. I have a file that contains a number on each line, there are approximately 5 millions rows, each row has a different number, how do i find the top 5 values in the file using spark and python.

Comment: A day has passed, but you don't react, should I worry?

Answer (score 1):

1. You distribute the data you read among nodes.
2. Every node finds it's 5 local maximums.
3. You combine all the local maximums and you keep the 5 max of them,
   which is the answer.

Comment: What if one node has the two biggest datapoints? Wouldn't we ignore the second biggest?